# Menu list across multiple sites using only HTML & CSS

Tags: html, css

Is there a way to share HTML across multiple pages? For e.g., a common menu bar or footer. I know this can be done using php include, however the webserver that I have space on allows only HTML/CSS.

Comment: Nope. If you had Python, you could do this really quickly with Flask and it's template engine.

Comment: Not a very good host if they doesn't allow server side scripting. They might still support Server Side Includes though.

Comment: @Andre... it's not a pro host; just a lousy university server. They don't allow server side scripting to avoid maintaining it. There isn't much that can go wrong with plain HTML.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it using jQuery and AJAX calls, if you really have to do the inclusion client-side. Use something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'http://www.example.com/header.htm',
        success: function(data) {
            $("#header").html(data);
        },
    });
}
</script>
```

You then just need to put a div with an id of 'header' (or whatever you replaced `#header` with in that script above) into the body of your HTML like so:

```
<div id="header"></div>
```

That should do the trick. Obviously it's better to do it server side - as anybody with Javascript turned off wouldn't see any files 'included' in this way, but your question covers the reasons behind this!

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use Javascript and AJAX calls to get the common HTML content and dynamically insert it in your page body.

Another solution would be to use iframes.

Comment: I know... I always try to never user them but they can be useful in some last resort situations

Answer (score 0):

Save the HTML as a string in an included JavaScript file and use innerHTML() to render it into a  element on your pages. You can trigger rendering by an onLoad() attribute in your  tag.

JavaScript file:
var html= "your HTML code";

HTML page:
...

...

...